# traversing ruby map issues

Tags: ruby

I'm pulling the following XML from mediawiki API

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <api>
      <query>
            <pages>
                 <page pageid="309311" ns="0" title="Chenonetta     jubata">
                 <images>
                     <im ns="6" title="File:Australian Wood Duck.jpg" />
                     <im ns="6" title="File:Australian Wood Duck Female.JPG" />
                     <im ns="6" title="File:Australian Wood Duck Male.JPG" />  
                     ...
                 </images>
                 </page>
            </pages>
     </query>
  </api>
```

and reading it into a Ruby map using xmlSimple. The data which I'm really trying to get is the image names from the images section but when I attempt to go past the query level with

```
     x=  result['query']['pages']
     puts x
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
   in `[]': can't convert String into Integer (TypeError)
```

what am I doing wrong?

Thanks, 
m

Comment: Could you do a `p result` to see its content, also although not as correct you could get what you want with `images = data.scan(/File:(.*)"/)`

Comment: How about showing us all of your code? result is an Array which is why it's raising as you're expecting a Hash

Comment: I'm new to Ruby and have the same issue, pissed off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used Nokogiri in the end which allows xpath notation to traverse the xml tree. 
e.g.

```
 licenseinfo = results3.xpath("//api/query/pages/page/categories/cl/@title")
```